# Dimension of subspace of all upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $S$ is the subspace of $M_7(R)$  consisting of all upper triangular matrices, then $dim(S)$ = ?

So if I have an upper triangular matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & . & . & a_{17}\\
. & a_{22} & . & . & a_{27}\\
.  & . & . & . & .\\
0 & . & . & . & a_{77}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It looks to me that this matrix can potentially have 7 pivots, therefore it is linearly independent and so it will take all 7 column vectors to span it. But that answer is marked as incorrect when I enter it so what am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking of the dimension of the row or column space - how might you write a matrix in co-ordinates? In other words, how many values do you have to specify in order to uniquely determine an upper triangular matrix in $M_7(R)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the answer is 1+2+3+...+7=28. Because every element in matrices in S can be a base in that space.

Comment: I dont understand this, anyone able to enlighten me?? I thought S being a subspace of $M_7$ meant I am dealing with all possible upper triangular 7x7 matrices, whereas you seem to be saying the subspace includes matrices of dimensions 1, 2,...,7?

Comment: A basis of $M_7(R)$ is given by the set of matrices with a $1$ in a single entry and $0$s elsewhere - there are $49$ of these. As you have no restrictions on the values of $a_{11},a_{12},\ldots,a_{77}$, the same argument works here and you can just count the number of entries which can be non-zero.

Answer (score 5):

In general, an $n\times n$ matrix has $n(n-1)/2$ off-diagonal coefficients and $n$ diagonal coefficients. Thus the dimension of the subalgebra of upper triangular matrices is equal to $n(n-1)/2+n=n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether it is a subspace. If yes, in order to determine the dimension, no need to find a basis. Just count the **degree of freedoms**, which is equal to the dimension. I think this method applies to more complicated spaces.